# Can we Pass the Values using sendkeys in selenium to select a item from a Bootstrap drop down menu?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I have a requirement where i have to pass the values for a bootstrap drop down menu using selenium instead of selecting. How can i achieve this? Is there anyway that we could do it using sendkeys in selenium?
Below is the code here i have to pass the values CSS,HTML,Java script instead of selecting them while automating.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdown Example</h2>
  <p>The data-toggle="dropdown" attribute is used to open the dropdown menu.</p>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by pass the value? You can't send text to a list element.

Comment: i mean i have to pass the list elements i.e HTML,Css,Javascript these values using sendkeys.

Comment: Pass them where? Do you mean you need to retrieve the element text?

Comment: Here i can find the xpath of the drop down, and after that i have to pass the elements using send keys to select the drop down items, instead of clicking on the elements.. my question is that possible to select the elements in the dropdown using sendkeys.

Comment: Ah right I get it now. You want to navigate to the dropdown element using the keyboard? Use sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) to move down to the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to select a dropdown list item with your keyboard:

```java
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

This code should for example select your element Javascript, after you've clicked on the button to open the dropdown.

**edit**

To find the position of your element in the dropdown you're going to have to count. You can do this as follows:

```java
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(ul.dropdown-menu > li));

for(WebElement element : elements) {
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
    if(element.getText().equals("Javascript") {
        element.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it's correct, but suppose i have a list of items say selecting cities where i have to select the city, here my selection will randomly change, so i have to use excel sheet where i can change the city names very often. from the excel sheet i am passing the values to select in the dropdown. so if i give like  driver.findElement(By.xpath(( "//*[@id=''menu1]"))).sendkeys("value to be passed"); so in this field i have to give the city name where i can select it. how can i do it?